# OpenShift Metrics Cartridge

Tags: openshift, metrics

OpenShift Metrics Cartridge - is it still available to install?
When I try install it to working application it says that

```
There are no cartridges that match 'metrics-0.1'.
```

If so, what tool allow to measure application performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that cartridge is no longer available.  You should try running something like New Relic or a similar service instead.